# Прокрутка содержимого в модальном окне bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

На странице выводится модальное окно

```
<div id="modal_gp" class="modal" role="document">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ГП, повлиявшие на показатель</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="table_gp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal_close" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Содержимое этого окна заполняется через ajax, т.е.

```
$("#table_gp").html(msg);
```

Таблица (#table_gp) может содержать 2 строки, а может и 10.
Сейчас при 10 строках в таблице окно растягивается вниз за экран и не прокручивается.
Как сделать, чтобы содержимое модального окна можно было прокручивать и окно не уходила за экран.

Comment: как вариант, использовать JScrollPane для модального окна. Самому модальному окну задать position fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю достаточно будет задать `.modal-body` значения `max-height` и `overflow-y`

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 300px; // например
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```